# Is it possible to log in to Google from a different website?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, google-docs

I use Google Docs to handle some documents, which i display on my website through the publish feature.

Is it possible to log on to Google automatically through my own site? If so, wouldnt have to log in two different places if i need to edit some documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change your website to authenticate using google openid? If so, then you could use your google account to sign into your own website and that would guarantee you're also signed into google. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID.

Answer (score 0):

There this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#what_can_this_api_do